# OpenCL doesn't detect GPU

Tags: gpu, opencl

I installed AMD APP SDK and here my problem. The OpenCL samples do not detect the GPU. HelloWorld give me this:

```
[thomas@Clemence:/opt/AMDAPP/samples/opencl/bin/x86_64]$ ./HelloWorld
No GPU device available.
Choose CPU as default device.
input string:
GdkknVnqkc

output string:
HelloWorld
Passed!
```

And here the clinfo output

```
[thomas@Clemence:~/Documents/radeontop]$ clinfo
Number of platforms:                 1
Platform Profile:                FULL_PROFILE
Platform Version:                OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)
Platform Name:               AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Platform Vendor:                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Platform Extensions:                 cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback      cl_amd_offline_devices


Platform Name:               AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:               1
Device Type:                     CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
Device ID:                   4098
Board name:                  
Max compute units:               8
Max work items dimensions:           3
Max work items[0]:               1024
Max work items[1]:               1024
Max work items[2]:               1024
Max work group size:                 1024
Preferred vector width char:             16
Preferred vector width short:            8
Preferred vector width int:          4
Preferred vector width long:             2
Preferred vector width float:            8
Preferred vector width double:       4
Native vector width char:            16
Native vector width short:           8
Native vector width int:             4
Native vector width long:            2
Native vector width float:           8
Native vector width double:          4
Max clock frequency:                 3633Mhz
Address bits:                    64
Max memory allocation:           4182872064
Image support:               Yes
Max number of images read arguments:         128
Max number of images write arguments:        8
Max image 2D width:              8192
Max image 2D height:                 8192
Max image 3D width:              2048
Max image 3D height:                 2048
Max image 3D depth:              2048
Max samplers within kernel:          16
Max size of kernel argument:             4096
Alignment (bits) of base address:        1024
Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:  128
Single precision floating point capability
Denorms:                     Yes
Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
Round to nearest even:           Yes
Round to zero:               Yes
Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
Cache type:                  Read/Write
Cache line size:                 64
Cache size:                  32768
Global memory size:              16731488256
Constant buffer size:                65536
Max number of constant args:             8
Local memory type:               Global
Local memory size:               32768
Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:   1
Error correction support:            0
Unified memory for Host and Device:      1
Profiling timer resolution:          1
Device endianess:                Little
Available:                   Yes
Compiler available:              Yes
Execution capabilities:              
Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
Execute native function:             Yes
Queue properties:                
Out-of-Order:                No
Profiling :                  Yes
Platform ID:                     0x00007f4ef63f0fc0
Name:                        Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Vendor:                  GenuineIntel
Device OpenCL C version:             OpenCL C 1.2 
Driver version:              1214.3 (sse2,avx)
Profile:                     FULL_PROFILE
Version:                     OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)
Extensions:                  cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64     cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_device_fission cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_amd_popcnt
```

What should I do in order to have access to the GPU? Thanks in advance. I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Trusty Kernel 3.9

here my graphics card:

```
[thomas@elsa:~]$ lspci | grep -i --color 'vga'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th 
Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
Oland XT [Radeon HD 8670 / R7 250/350]
```

Answer (score 3):

I should warn you that I don't really know anything about linux or programming or device drivers, but I had your exact problem once.

It could be a udev rule problem. Your usergroup might not have permission to write to the gpu device or whatever libOpenCL.so does. Does `$ sudo clinfo` find the gpu?

Your program might not be using the right opencl library. I think that there is some ubuntu packages that provide libopencl.so. You don't want to use those, they won't know how to talk to your gpu. Could you post:

```
$ ldd /opt/AMDAPP/samples/opencl/bin/x86_64/HelloWorld
```

If the libOpenCL.so* line (sometimes libcl.so*) doesn't point to a AMD library, you need to find the AMD libOpenCL.so library and make sure that it is found first before whatever you're using at runtime.

I would do `$ sudo updatedb` then,

```
$ locate libOpenCL.so
```

or

```
$ locate libcl.so
```

depending on which your `./HelloWorld` is trying to link to. Then set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the parent folder of the preferred library.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path to lib*cl.so* that was installed by AMD driver/ 
$ clinfo
$ ./HelloWorld
```

Comment: clinfo did not work, but sudo clinfo did for me.

Answer (score 1):

I too could not see my GPU through clinfo.

The fix for me was disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS which did not let the Ubuntu kernel load DKMS code. There was even a ncurses warning after installing the driver, in my case AMDGPU PRO 16.60 on Ubuntu 16.10.

I hope this helps!